# How are incremental updates rolled out to a subset of customers on a website?

Tags: deployment, gmail, web-deployment, continuous

How do the guys like Google/Gmail/Facebook do incremental releases?  For example, on the implementation side, what do they do to roll out features to a subset of customers?  I can think of two possible implementations:

1. Effectively put `if` statements around code on both the front-end and the back-end.
2. If you have customer affinity for certain application servers, you could deploy to just a subset of application servers.

The first just seems kind of hacky to me, and the second seems hard if you are using an RDBMS for your backend store.

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate testing is a commonly adopted approach.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_testing

Comment: I'm looking for more concrete examples of how a system like this is implemented.  Not an analysis method once you've done it.